# .read() returns "unicode object has no attribute read" in python with askopenfilename()

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter, attributeerror

I'm trying to make an import function for scrolledText in Python's Tkinter, but when reading the file, an AttributeError is raised. Code:

```
def open_command():
    openfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if openfile != None:
        contents = openfile.read()
        textPad.delete('1.0', END)
        textPad.insert('1.0', contents)
        openfile.close()
```

Error:

```
    contents = openfile.read()
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I want to clarify that 'textPad' refers to a 'ScrolledText' object.
Does anyone know why this is happening? at first I thought the error may be coming from encoding, so I encoded in UTF-8 but it still returned the same error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `askopenfilename` returns a file _name`. You can't call `read()` on a filename, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()` returns the file name not a file object. You'll want to do something like:

```
def open_command():  
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if filename is not None:
        with open(filename) as f:
           contents = f.read()
        textPad.delete('1.0', END)
        textPad.insert('1.0', contents)
```

[If you're using Python 2.7 consider using Python 3 or change the above to `open(filename, 'r')`]

Comment: Many thanks! Is there a specific reason to switch to Python 3? I'm more used to Python 2.7.

Comment: Python 2.7 will not be maintained after 2020. Python 3 has a bunch of useful features and newer modules will not be supporting 2.7. If you do anything at all with strings/unicode, it will be utter relief to switch. https://pythonclock.org/